# Holding an array of T within a template<T> class

Tags: templates, c++-cli, queue, adt

I'm trying to develop a template class for a queue and getting the error `error C3265: cannot declare a managed 'items' in an unmanaged 'TQueue<T>'`. From what I understand I can't have managed types within an unmanaged "class". My code is as follows:

```
#pragma once

template<class T> class TQueue
{
private:
    array<T>^ items;
    int currentIndex;
    int count;
public:
    TQueue();
    void Enqueue(T toAdd);
    T Dequeue();

    GetCount() {return currentIndex;}
};
```

How would I go about holding an array of type `<T>` in my Queue?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: You might want to fix the question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply included the 'ref' in the class prototype. I accidentally deleted it causing the class to become 'unmanaged'.

The class prototype ended up as: `template<class T> ref class TQueue`